# botframework-webchat v3 and botframework sdk v4 support

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am currently working on migration clients' botframework-webchat v3 solutions to v4. According to the v4 webchat docs, there is full support for botframework-sdk v4. However, I am wondering what the support for pre-existing botframework-webchat v3 solutions is for botframework-sdk v4?

Some clients may not wish to migrate their botframework-webchat solutions at the moment, and I am trying to determine the effect of using botframework-sdk v4 would have on their current botframework-webchat v3 solutions.

Comment: refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-webchat-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#migrating-from-web-chat-v3-to-v4 and https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2370

Answer (score 2):

v3 was moved to the following [GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-v3). And according to the README file:

> Microsoft Bot Framework SDK V4 was released in September 2018, and since then we have shipped a few dot-release improvements. As announced previously, the V3 SDK is being retired with final long-term support ending on December 31st, 2019. Accordingly, there will be no more development in this repo. Existing V3 bot workloads will continue to run without interruption. We have no plans to disrupt any running workloads.
> We highly recommend that you start migrating your V3 bots to V4. In order to support this migration we have produced migration documentation and will provide extended support for migration initiatives (via standard channels such as Stack Overflow and Microsoft Customer Support).

This means that support for v3 has ended, but it will continue to run without any interruptions.

Comment: My understanding is that this is referring to existing Botframework SDK v3 implementations. However, I would like to find out if there is any impact this has on BotFramework-Webchat (in particular v3) or are the two libraries completely independent from each other?